# Подсказка при наборе текста в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

Пытаюсь сделать всплывающую подсказку для input, чтобы пользователь мог по первым введенным символам увидеть какие варианты доступны.
Используя jQuery это сделать не так сложно, вот пример:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Но насколько я знаю использование в ReactJS подобных библиотек которые изменяют DOM не рекомендуется. Отсюда вопрос: как сделать это с использованием ReactJS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

Answer (score 0):

Есть событие onInput={handleInput} в нем отправляете запрос на сервер с где указываете текущее состояние символов в поле и по ним делаете сортировку в базе данных и отдаете json-ом и в автокомплите уже рендерите этот json. onInput срабатывает на каждое действие в поле.

Comment: Полагаю в таком случае  можно использовать и onChange ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256332/in-react-whats-the-difference-between-onchange-and-oninput все подробно расписано.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп. А в какой части писать логику запроса к серверу если я использую Redux? Я это делаю там же где находится функция reducer, но чувствую что это не совсем верно?

Comment: Да нет, как раз все правильно делаете, посмотрите redux-thunk.